# Console.log cannot show in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, console.log

My javascript is using jQuery. However, when I clicked the #button_execute,  the console.log in the callback function of .done didn't print anything on my console. I am not sure how can I console.log them.

```
$("#button_execute").click(function() {

    var htmlContainer = htmlGraphContent(); 
    var graphContext = returnGraphContext();
    var formData = extractFormData();
    var buildingId = formData.buildingId;
    var zoneId = formData.zoneId;
    var dateExtracted = formData.dateExtracted;
    var url = "/api/building/" + buildingId + "/zone/" + zoneId + "/" + dateExtracted;

    sendJqueryRequest("GET", url)
        .done(function(data) {
        console.log("#button_execute - data.data.result:",data.data.result);
        buttonPlayLayout();
        var resultArray = data.data.result;
        htmlContainer.collapse("show");
        lastDataRetrieved = resultArray;
        console.log( "#button_execute_bms - sendJqueryRequest(\"GET\"," + url + ")");
        startRealTimeGraph(resultArray, graphContext, formData);
        console.log("real_time_graph.js - #button_execute_bms - lastDataRetrieved:",lastDataRetrieved);
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            alertCreator(error, "#bms-container", "bms-alert");
        });
 });
```

This is sendJqueryRequest

```
var sendJqueryRequest = function (type, url, data) {       
    var jsonToSend = {type: type, url: url};
    console.log("sendJqueryRequest");
    if(data) { 
        jsonToSend.data = data; 
        console.log("sendJqueryRequest jsonToSend: "+jsonToSend);
    }
    console.log(jsonToSend.url);
    return $.ajax(jsonToSend);
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're saying the rest of your code is working, e.g., you are seeing AJAX requests being sent, etc. the only thing not working is you aren't seeing console.log messages?

Comment: Yes, the only thing doesn't work is the console.log function.

Comment: Works fine in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/0ftbjnm8/)... it logs an error message because it's jsfiddle, but nothing is wrong with this.

Comment: So what is button_execute? A submit button? Is the Ajax call erroring out?

Comment: And if you add a console.log to the top of your JavaScript (outside of any function) *that* works. Multiple browsers show same behavior?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Thanks. Your snippets work well, but mine still can't.

Comment: @epascarello button_execute is a submit button. I update the whole jQuery function.

Comment: All codes in .done work, such as buttonPlayLayout and startRealTimeGraph working well, but only console.log doesn't show.

Comment: @aquinas No, it doesn't work when I put a console.log on the top of this js file. I am not sure why. I have tested Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 52.7.3 (64-bit).

Comment: You did not cancel the button click. Submit buttons submit. Page reloads and the http request will be cancelled. `.click(function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); `

Comment: @epascarello I have add $("#button_execute_bms").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
in the first line of the jQuery click callback function, but it still doesn't print out.

Comment: So did you step through it with a debugger statement? Add log lines?

Comment: @epascarello sorry for the late response. I realised that's because of a really silly situation: I didn't realise that the console.log of front-end js will post to the console of the browser, not the console of the terminal. Sorry for wasting so much time on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that's because of a really silly situation: I didn't realise that the console.log of front-end js will post to the console of the browser, not the console of the terminal. Sorry for wasting you guys so much time on this issue.